# tableauserverclient - NotSignedInError despite using correct data

Tags: python, tableau-api

I'm trying to connect tableau server with **Python** and **tableauserverclient** module, but I get this message when I'm trying to use users.get_by_id() func:

```
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/bi_reporting_platform/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tableauserverclient/server/endpoint/users_endpoint.py", line 22, in baseurl
    return "{0}/sites/{1}/users".format(self.parent_srv.baseurl, self.parent_srv.site_id)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/bi_reporting_platform/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tableauserverclient/server/server.py", line 164, in site_id
    raise NotSignedInError(error)
tableauserverclient.server.exceptions.NotSignedInError: Missing site ID. You must sign in first.
```

I'm not sure why this is happening, but I suspect that the auth_endpoint class is somehow failing to parse out the site id from the sign-in server response. But why is that?

The minimal relevant snippet (I censored the username and password):

```
tableau_auth = TSC.TableauAuth(<username>, <password>, site_id="")
def users_cleanup(threshold_in_days=90, bck_file='removed_users', id_to_update):
    .
    .
    .
    with dev_server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):
         ...
         user = dev_server.users.get_by_id(id_to_update)
         ...
```

I want to emphasize that this code worked perfectly few days ago. Help anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly giving an empty string for `site_id` is preventing the login from succeeding.  If you want the default then skip the argument.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tableauserverclient as TSC
import pprint

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=2)

# create an auth object
tableau_auth = TSC.TableauAuth(<username>, <password>)

# create an instance for your server
server = TSC.Server('https://tableau.company.com')

# call the sign-in method with the auth object
with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):

  all_users, pagination_item = server.users.get()
  print("\nThere are {} user on site: ".format(pagination_item.total_available))
  print([user.name for user in all_users])
  sample_user = server.users.get_by_id(all_users[0].id)
  pp.pprint(sample_user)
```